# Do these graphs fulfill assumptions of linear model?

Tags: regression, model, linear, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

[image]

Hi,

I can see that there is a slight trend in the Scale-Location graph. I'm wondering if this is neglible enough to go ahead with a linear model?

thanks!

Eamon

Comment: This looks quite good to me, or to put it differently: many people run regressions with much worse residual properties. if your goal is inference and you are really worried about heteroscedasticity affecting your standard errors (based on the scale-location plot), go for robust standard errors

Comment: FAQ: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+diagnostic+plot